# Images not populating div

Tags: javascript, html

trying to create a simple slideshow with javascript for a class. For some reason the images are not loading into the div.

script:

```
var imageArray = ['img/br1.jpg', 'img/br2.jpg', 'img/br3.png', 'img/br4.gif', 'img/br5.jpeg', 'img/br6.jpeg', 'img/br7.jpeg'];
var i = 0;

function slideShow() {
document.getElementById('slideshowdiv').src = imageArray[i];

//increment i by 1
i++;

// checks if i is greater than or equal to the length
if(i >= imageArray.length) {
    // if true, resets value to 0
    i = 0;
};

//recall the change function every 2 seconds
timer = setTimeout('slideShow()', 2000);

}
function stopShow() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
};
```

html:

```
<body onload="slideShow()">
<div id="slideshowdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout` nor `setInterval` with strings, because it's like evil `eval`! Use functions instead: `setTimeout(slideShow, 2000)`

Comment: Checked the console for errors?

Comment: yea, there's none. @j08691

Comment: Does the `src` attribute of a `div` load an image? Shouldn't you be using an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`slideshowdiv` does not have a `.src` because it's a `<div>` and not an `<img>`

This:

```
document.getElementById('slideshowdiv').src = imageArray[i];
```

Should be like:

```
var div = document.getElementById('slideshowdiv');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<img src="' + imageArray[i] + '" />';
```

Comment: You can use `+=` to avoid repeating `div.innerHTML`

Comment: @trev Are you getting `<img>` written into the `div`?

Comment: okay, so the images load into the div now, but I need them to load on top of eachother. right now they just cascade down. -edit- nevermind, got it, just had to delete the extra div.innerHTML. Thanks for the help. @Biotox

Comment: You don't need to append, simply replace all the `div` content.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few potential bugs here.

1. First of all, I think you want to be using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. The usage is the same, you only need to change the function name. You *could* just call your `slideShow` function once (as you do in the onload call), and let the timeouts chain, but this leads us to the next problem.
2. The `timer` variable is not declared outside the scope of your `slideshow` function. This means that your `stopShow` function will not be able to see it. You will want to call `var timer = setInterval(slideShow, 2000)` after all of your code, in this example. You are actually getting away with bug by not declaring `var` before your variables.
3. Finally, I don't think setting the `src` attribute of a `<div>` element is what you want to be doing.

The simplest solution is to append an `<img>` tag to your `<div>` like so:

```
var div = document.getElementById('slideshowdiv');
div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + imageArray[i] + '" />';
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I just added from the answer above. Thanks for the info.